# Django {% trans %} template tag giving DjangoUnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, utf-8, internationalization

We are trying to implement i18n into our Django 1.7.4 web app.
Successfully created .mo and .po files,
Hebrew .po file:

```
#: templates/community/profile.html:109
msgid "Games"
msgstr "משחקים"
```

Some contain Hebrew characters (non ascii) ,
I created a small template that only has this:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Games" %}
```

Getting error:

```
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError at /community/testtrans/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in     range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at     0x05A29550> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```

I noticed the generated .PO file was compiled as ASCII, try changing to UTF-8, didn't help

These tests passed fine:

- Writing the Hebrew text directly in the HTML file
- Passing a view parameter `viewParams['trans_games'] = _("Games")` and then displaying it on the template with `{{trans_games}}`

We tried it on two local computers : Windows & Mac

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/5-EjBFQoeyU

Turns out I had to add this header to the .po file

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

Comment: It's unfortunate you were downvoted. After working with i18n information for years, I ran into this today. After banging my head against the wall, having never run into this, I finally discovered this Q+A via Google. Adding the aforementioned line to my PO file's meta-data solved the problem for me (Django 1.9). See also the meta-data here: https://polib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-po-catalogs-from-scratch